# Laravel and AD connection using directorytree/ldaprecord-laravel bringing error while authenticating

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I am trying to authenticate an AD user in laravel using the `directorytree/ldaprecord-laravel` package.

I have installed the package and followed the steps as shown in the package install. The script for authenticating looks like this

```
$connection = Container::getConnection('default');

$user = User::findByOrFail('samaccountname', 'sbauman');

if ($connection->auth()->attempt($user->getDn(), 'SuperSecret')) {
     // Credentials are valid!
}
```

However, I am getting the following error when I try logging in:

```
message: "LdapRecord\\Laravel\\LdapUserRepository::createModel(): Return value must be of type LdapRecord\\Models\\Model, App\\Models\\User returned"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried extending your User model to, LdapRecord\Models\Model ? and added your LDAP classes to public static array $objectClasses ?

As per [documentation](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/core/v3/models#defining-models), you must, add public static property that contains the object classes of the LDAP record.

These object classes are used to locate the proper objects in your LDAP directory.

```
<?php

use LdapRecord\Models\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public static array $objectClasses = [
      'top',
      'person',
      'organizationalperson',
      'user',
];
}
```